# Grouping selectors by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<table>
  <tr id="groupItem-12863">
    <td>10</td>
    <td class="selCost">34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-12863">
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="selCost">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td class="selCost">23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-73632">
    <td>28</td>
    <td class="selCost">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-73632">
    <td>54</td>
    <td class="selCost">55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-73632">
    <td>13</td>
    <td class="selCost">99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td class="selCost">55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>99</td>
    <td class="selCost">66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want a jquery selector where I can loop over the group of id and fetch the value of td cell. Note: the tr id are generated dynamically and can have none or N rows for each group of id. For example  (groupItem-12863 has 2 and groupItem-73632 has 3 rows)

Comment: Ideally, a HTML should not have same IDs. You can have same class to multiple tags, but IDs should be unique. How about using custom attributes and achieving what you are looking for?

Comment: So when your group covers multiple rows, exactly which "td cell" (single in the question) would you be expecting to retrieve?

Comment: If you're grouping rows, you should be assigning unique ids to tbody elements instead of assigning the same id to multiple tr elements. If this HTML isn't yours, though, not much can be said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do bit of hack, I know the html was not ideal, we can't have same id's. But sometimes refactoring the older code is out of scope. Here is the solution, not ideal but works :

```js
$('tr[id^=groupItem-]').each(function(){
 var s = 0 ;
  var text = $(this).attr('id');
  var arr = text.split('-');
  var elem = 'tr[id^=groupItem-' + arr[1] + ']';
    $(elem).find("td.selCost").each(function(){
   s += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
console.log($(this).attr('id')+ '=='+s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the following solution should do what you are expecting, I strongly suggest you to change the id to another attribute, a custom one like `group-id` or use CSS classes. By the way:

```
$(function() {
  var groupedRows = {};
  $.each($('tr[id^=groupItem]'), function() {
     if (groupedRows[$(this).attr('id')]) {
         groupedRows[$(this).attr('id')].push($(this));
     } 
     else {
         groupedRows[$(this).attr('id')] = [$(this)];
     }
  });
  console.log(groupedRows);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML must not have same ids, it will be better to use class for your use-case.

After this you can get the elements with a given class and loop over them like

```js
$(function(){
  $('.groupItem-73632').each(function() {
      console.log('grp');
      $(this).find('td').each(function(){
          console.log($(this).text());
      })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    
      <tr class="groupItem-12863">
        <td>10</td>
        <td class="selCost">34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="groupItem-12863">
        <td>20</td>
        <td class="selCost">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td class="selCost">23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="groupItem-73632">
        <td>28</td>
        <td class="selCost">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="groupItem-73632">
        <td>54</td>
        <td class="selCost">55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="groupItem-73632">
        <td>13</td>
        <td class="selCost">99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td class="selCost">55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>99</td>
        <td class="selCost">66</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the wildcard selector like `tr[id^=groupItem]`. Check [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr[id^=groupItem]').css({
    'background-color': 'red'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="groupItem-12863">
    <td>10</td>
    <td class="selCost">34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-12863">
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="selCost">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td class="selCost">23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-73632">
    <td>28</td>
    <td class="selCost">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-73632">
    <td>54</td>
    <td class="selCost">55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="groupItem-73632">
    <td>13</td>
    <td class="selCost">99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td class="selCost">55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>99</td>
    <td class="selCost">66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ummm, what if I want to color customize to each group? I can fetch the whole lot, what I need is a way to group them based on the ID.